# What is the Fastest Way to parse RSS feed in PHP?

Tags: php, rss

I have pulled 7 RSS feed and parse in our website. But the parse time is very slow, what is the best way to parse RSS feed in PHP.

Also is there a way to GZip for faster parse time?

I use this GZip in my .htaccess file but no difference

Here's the GZip script in my .htaccess file

```
# compress text, html, javascript, css, xml: AddOutputFilterByType
DEFLATE text/plain text/html text/xml text/css application/xml
application/xhtml+xml application/rss+xml application/javascript
application/x-javascript
```

Here's my PHP code to parse RSS feeds

```
<?php
function getFeed($feed_url){
    $content = file_get_contents($feed_url);
    $x = new SimpleXMLElement($content);

    for ($i=0; $i<=4; $i++){
        $entry = $x->channel->item[$i];

            // if promotion price is set, then use the promotion price instead of Normal Price
            $normal = $entry->NormalPrice;
            $promo  = $entry->PromotionPrice;

            // Get the links and titles
            $image = $entry->Image->Url;
            $link = $entry->link;
            $title = $entry->title;

            if((isset($promo)) && ($promo > 0)){
                $price = 'R '.number_format(trim($promo), 2);
            }else if($normal > 0 && $promo == 0){
                $price = 'R '.number_format(trim($normal), 2);
            }else if((empty($normal) && empty($promo)) || (($normal == 0) && ($promo == 0))){
                $price = 'Out Of Stock';
            }


                echo '<div class="rssImages">';
                echo '<div class="imageCover">';
                echo '<a href="'.$link.'"><img src="'.$image.'" /></a><br /><br />';
                echo '</div>';
                echo '<div class="rssCntImg">';
                echo '<a href="'.$link.'" id="rsslinks">'.$title.'</a> <br />';
                echo '</div>';
                echo '<strong>'.$price."</strong>";
                echo '<label class="cleared"></label>';
                echo '</div>';          
    }
}
?>
```

any help/suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: It's only as "slow" as the server that serves the feed...

Comment: Have you timed the different steps and found your bottleneck? 

GZip in Apache has to with output encoding, from your server to your visitors. Downloading external feeds with GZip will save bandwidth (and download speed), but increase the processor load and add extra time for unpacking the response.

Comment: Yep, @alex seems to have a point. Try to compare the execution speed of your code as it is now with that of some code that simply reads out the XML from the selected feeds. I strongly doubt the bottleneck is in  the parsing itself. 

Also, if that is the problem, I have reasons to suspect that you might be getting the rss from the remote host with every page load. That is bad. Cache.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you are parsing your feeds online, on each and every user request.
It always would be slow. It is network, you know.

The only sensible way of reading RSS feeds is *asynchronous* one. One script to parse them regularily and update the *local* database and another to show entries from the local database.

And, you know, gzipping *output* has very little to do with parsing *inbound* data. Go figure.

Comment: "update the local database", this gives me good idea. I made cronjob that update all the RSS feeds every morning at 3Am and store the data into database and images into folder, that is the fastest way :) Got it solved that way.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that Gzip could have a positive influence on the parse time, it will decrease the download time but that's all.

You should consider using the SAX parser instead of simplexml :

[Php Doc about SAX Parser](http://php.net/manual/en/book.xml.php)
[An example](http://www.pixel2life.com/publish/tutorials/35/the_ultimate_guide_to_parsing_xml_part_1_using_sax_/)

SAX parser is faster than simplexml on big file (if it well used). The memory use by the sax parser is lower too.

have a look on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2604277/which-is-much-faster-xmlparser-or-simplexml/2604319#2604319)

Comment: Your example is not an example of an SAX parser. It uses DOMDocument, which is not an SAX parser.

Answer (score 0):

Summary of comments and answers:

- Make sure you only parse when needed, check for updates separately and serve information from a local DB on page requests.
- Make sure the latency isn't due to slow response from the remote servers (again, this will be alleviated by caching).
- Unless the feeds are HUGE, any XML parser will do, and if they are HUGE, that might be the cause of the latency...
- GZip, as stated is server side, you can specify that the client (your script) accepts gzip, using for instance cURL, but usage of cURL is a question that should be asked separately. It will in any event do nothing to decrease parse time.